How to make the Google column chart tool tip to appear right above the column where mouse is pointed
In the Google column chart the tooltip appears towards the right of the column where mouse is pointed. How can this be changed so that it appears right above the column.
In the code, options are
var options = {
        title: "Spending - Last 7 days",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFAF5",
        width: width,
        height: height,
        chartArea: { left: "5%", right: "5%", top: "25%", bottom: "10%" },
        bar: { groupWidth: "68%" },
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: "#382314",
          fontName: "DM Sans",
          fontSize: 24,
        },
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
        allowHtml: true,
        vAxis: {
          textPosition: "none",
          baselineColor: "none",
          gridlines: { count: 0 },
        },
        hAxis: {
          textStyle: { color: "#93867B", fontName: "DM Sans" },
        },
        legend: { position: "none" },
        colors: [chartColor],
      };

CSS for tooltip is:
.google-visualization-tooltip {
        color: white !important;
        background-color: rgb(11, 11, 11) !important;
        font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif !important;
        border-radius: 18% !important;
        padding: 0.3% 0.3% 0.3% 0.3% !important;
        align-content: center !important;

        border: none !important;

        z-index: +1;
      }


I tried implmenting the solution suggested in How does google-visualization-tooltip calculate the left and top values?. But it didn't work. The chart didn't come up. I didn't try debussing it since I was not sure if that solution works in my case.
Now it shows like this

and this is what is expected.


the answer you found should work. will you please share the code used to draw your chart?

Please find the code - https://github.com/Aparnagopal/ExpenseReportFrontend

Thanks. It worked. Where can I find good documentation on how to customize Google charts?

The answer you reference draws a line chart, whereas you are working with a column chart.
as such, you need to change the following line, from "point#" to "bar#"
      var pointBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox(
        "bar#" + (sender.column - 1) + "#" + sender.row
      );

see following working snippet...


google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(fetchJSONData);

function fetchJSONData() {
      var datavis = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ["Country", "Mhl", { role: "tooltip", p: { html: true } }],
       ["Italy", 54.8, "54.8T"],
       ["France", 48.6, "54.8T"],
       ["Spain", 44.4, "54.8T"],
       ["USA", 23.9, "54.8T"],
       ["Argentina", 14.5, "54.8T"],
      ]);

      // Set Options
      var width = 0.3 * window.innerWidth;
      var height = 0.4 * window.innerHeight;
      var chartColor = "#ec775f";
      var options = {
        title: "Spending - Last 7 days",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFAF5",
        width: width,
        height: height,
        chartArea: { left: "5%", right: "5%", top: "25%", bottom: "10%" },
        bar: { groupWidth: "68%" },
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: "#382314",
          fontName: "DM Sans",
          fontSize: 24,
        },
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
        allowHtml: true,
        vAxis: {
          textPosition: "none",
          baselineColor: "none",
          gridlines: { count: 0 },
        },
        hAxis: {
          textStyle: { color: "#93867B", fontName: "DM Sans" },
        },
        legend: { position: "none" },
        colors: [chartColor],
      };

      // Draw

      var container = document.getElementById("columnchart_material");
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        "ready",
        changeBorderRadius
      );

      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        "select",
        changeBorderRadius
      );
      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        "onmouseover",
        chartMouseOver
      );
      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        "onmouseout",
        chartMouseOut
      );
      chart.clearChart();
      chart.draw(datavis, options);

      //window.addEventListener("resize", fetchJSONData, false);

      function changeBorderRadius() {
        chartColumns = container.getElementsByTagName("rect");
        //console.log("chart column" + chartColumns);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartColumns, function (column) {
          column.setAttribute("rx", 6);
          column.setAttribute("ry", 6);
          column.setAttribute("stroke", "none");
          column.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0);
        });
      }

      function setBarOpacity(index, opacity) {
        var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
          document.getElementById("columnchart_material")
        );
        // filter bars by fill color
        var chartBars = chart1
          .getContainer()
          .querySelectorAll(
            'rect[fill="' + "#ec775f" + '"],rect[fill="' + "#76b5bc" + '"]'
          );

        // console.log("chartBars" + chartBars[index]);
        // chartBars[index].setAttribute("stroke", "none");
        //chartBars[index].setAttribute("stroke-width", 0);
        // set opacity on index provided
        chartBars[index].setAttribute("opacity", opacity);
      }

      function chartMouseOver(sender) {
        changeBorderRadius();
        // set opacity to 0.5

        setBarOpacity(sender.row, 0.8);

        // ensure point is hovered
        if (sender.row !== null) {
          var padding = 16;
          var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
          var pointBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox(
            "bar#" + (sender.column - 1) + "#" + sender.row
          );
          var tooltip = chart
            .getContainer()
            .getElementsByClassName("google-visualization-tooltip");
          if (tooltip.length > 0) {
            var tooltipBounds = tooltip[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            tooltip[0].style.top =
              pointBounds.top - tooltipBounds.height - padding + "px";
            tooltip[0].style.left =
              pointBounds.left +
              pointBounds.width / 2 -
              tooltipBounds.width / 2 +
              "px";
          }
        }
      }

      // chart mouseout event
      function chartMouseOut(sender) {
        // set opacity to 1

        changeBorderRadius();
        setBarOpacity(sender.row, 1);
      }
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital,opsz,wght@0,9..40,100..1000;1,9..40,100..1000&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Sedan:ital@0;1&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Expenses chart component</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <style>
      .attribution {
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .attribution a {
        color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
      }

      .main {
        display: block;
        width: fit-content;
        font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .main .chart {
        display: block;
      }

      .main .topbox {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }

      .main #total {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
      }

      .google-visualization-tooltip {
        color: white !important;
        background-color: rgb(11, 11, 11) !important;
        font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif !important;
        border-radius: 18% !important;
        padding: 0.3% 0.3% 0.3% 0.3% !important;
        align-content: center !important;

        border: none !important;

        z-index: +1;
      }

      @media screen and ((min-width: 320px) and (max-width:768px)) {
        .main {
          padding-left: 15%;
          padding-right: 15%;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./expensechart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="main"
      style="
        background-color: #f8e9dd;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 8%;
        padding-bottom: 8%;
        padding-left: 35%;
        padding-right: 35%;
      "
    >
      <div
        class="topbox"
        style="
          background-color: #ec775f;
          border-radius: 10px;
          padding-top: 4%;
          padding-bottom: 3%;
        "
      >
        <div
          id="top1"
          style="
            margin-left: 5%;
            color: #fffaf5;
            font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.5;
          "
        >
          <span
            style="
              font-size: 13px;
              font-weight: 200;
              font-stretch: extra-expanded;
            "
            >My balance</span
          >
          <div>
            <span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: 500">$921.48 </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: auto; padding-right: 5%">
          <img
            src="./images/logo.svg"
            alt=""
            style="width: 80%; margin-top: 10%"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="chart" style="background-color: #fffaf5; border-radius: 10px">
        <div id="columnchart_material"></div>
        <hr / style="color:#93867B ;width: 85%; opacity: 0.2;height:
        1px;background-color: #93867B;">
        <br />
        <div id="total">
          <div id="totcol1" style="padding-left: 5%">
            <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #93867b"
              >Total this month</span
            >
            <div>
              <span
                style="color: #382314; font-weight: bold; font-size: xx-large"
                >$478.33</span
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="totcol2" style="margin-left: auto; padding-right: 5%">
            <br />
            <span style="color: #382314; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px"
              >+2.4%</span
            >
            <div>
              <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #93867b"
                >from last month</span
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
      <br />

      <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by
        <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
          >Frontend Mentor</a
        >. Coded by <a href="#">Aparna Gopalakrishnan</a>.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



